# Add multiple objects to NSMutableArray from file list

Tags: objective-c

I am having a Picker View for selecting states(or prefectures for Europe).The current method i am using to populate the Picker View is the following:

in **viewDidLoad**

```
_arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[_arrayNo addObject:@" AL "];
[_arrayNo addObject:@" AK "];
[_arrayNo addObject:@" AZ "];
[_arrayNo addObject:@" Other "];
```

and then the usual pickerView delegate and dataSource. With the above code i don't have any issues. But apparantly if i want to add many states/town(let't say over 100) the array method would become hard to maintain.

My question is can i load the states into the array from a list in a file which resides inside the Supporting files folder? For example a file containing:

```
AL
AK
AZ
AR
CA
...
WI
WV
WI
Other
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a .plist file with the list and then load the plist file root dictionary keys/values into your array.

Comment: I'll try that,found already some sample code.I'll post results.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You load the file, parse the strings out of it (probably with `componentsSeparatedByString:`) and put them in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *arrayNo;


  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                      @"townsList" ofType:@"plist"];
  _arrayNo= [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Thanks for the guidance!